# How to count non-null values in table php

Tags: php, sql, null

[image]

How do I count **non-null** variables in php **database**?(SQL)

This is my existing code and database in the picture:

```
 $jack5 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM z3 WHERE ID='$users_Names' AND Score IS NOT NULL "));
 echo $jack5;
```

when I echo the result, I get:

> Notice: Array to string conversion etc... error

I'm new to this so any help is appreciated! 
z3 is my table name
Score is my column name

Comment: `select count(*) from z3 where score is not null`?

Comment: use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to print the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM z3 WHERE ID='$users_Names' AND Score IS NOT NULL "));
$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($result);  // It will return the number of rows in result set
```

Comment: i did this but it still gave me 7 results! im looking for a return value of 3. (exclude all the nulls)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$jack5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM z3 
          WHERE ID='$users_Names' AND Score IS NOT NULL");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($jack5))   
{ 
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of rows by using [COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) function.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM z3 
WHERE  
ID='$users_Names' 
AND Score IS NOT NULL
```

This will return you the count of rows having the given criteria in **WHERE** clause.

Comment: How do i echo the result? $test = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM z3 
WHERE  
ID='$users_Names' 
AND Score IS NOT NULL");

Comment: Do `print_r($test);`, First element of the array would be count of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    `$jack5 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM z3 
          WHERE     ID='$users_Names' AND Score IS NOT NULL "));
     echo $jack5;`